# regex for not start with 'the' and end with 'form'

Tags: regex

regex for not start with 'the' or end with 'form'. The input may have the or end form.
eg:

```
the test3211 form - valid
the test22 - not valid
test34 - valid
test55 form - not valid
```

The regex i tried
^the.*form$

Comment: `^(?!the).*form$`

Comment: Your regex is not working.

Comment: Then please add more details to the question: where you are using the regex, how you are using it.